# Anthrop\c Claude : LlamaIndex: The model requires further context to answer to the query

Tags: python-3.x, large-language-model, llama-index, anthropic, claude

## The use case

I am using LLamaIndex to query a pdf stored under the "data" directory

I am using Anthrop\c Claude as Large-Language Model (LLM)

## Question

What is the expected piece of code that I need to add in order to comply with the output message :

1. "Unfortunately I do not have enough context to fully summarize what the document is about without directly referencing the given context"
2. "Unfortunately, I do not have enough context to directly answer the query about the authors."

## The source code

```
# query the file stored under data/
from llama_index.llms import Anthropic

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()
llm = Anthropic(api_key=os.getenv('LLM_ANTHROPIC_API_KEY'))


from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader, ServiceContext
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(chunk_size=1024, llm=llm, embed_model="local")
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("data").load_data()

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context) 

query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
response = query_engine.query("What is the document about?")

print(response)

response = query_engine.query("Who are the authors?")
print(response)
```

## Answer 1 "What is the document about?" from Anthrop\c Claude

**Unfortunately I do not have enough context to fully summarize what the document is about without directly referencing the given context.**

Based on the page numbers and section titles provided, it seems to cover topics related to ....

**However, without further context I cannot conclusively state what the overall focus of the document is.**

**I apologize that I cannot provide a more specific summary without additional information.**

## Answer 2 "Who are the authors?" from Anthrop\c Claude

**Unfortunately, I do not have enough context to directly answer the query about the authors.**

The provided information discusses ... classification, ... and guidelines, but does not mention any authors.

**To provide a relevant response, more context related to the specific query would be needed.**